# Why does one image load but the other doesn't

Tags: visualforce, images

I have a formula field that loads an image based on a checkbox field. On the record it displays fine but on the related list on a visualforce page it breaks. A similar image loads in both instances.

On the contact record:
[image]

On the related list: 
[image]

Comment: Please provide in your original post the formulas you are using for both fields.

Answer (score 3):

Because Force.com is **CaSe SeNsItIvE**. The broken link icon says that it's trying to load ***C***onfirm24, but the actual file name is ***c***onfirm24. Check your formulas and make sure you're using the correct name.

Correct: [image]

Incorrect: [image]